# continuity of the derivative of the substitute in integration by substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

In section $5.7$ of Tom Apostol's calculus vol 1, integration by substitution is explained. Namely, he writes that:

$$
Q(x) = P[g(x)] \land \int f(x)dx = P(x) + C \implies \int f[g(x)] g'(x) dx = P[g(x)] + C
$$

And later writes that we can substitute $u = g(x)$ and $\frac{du}{dx} = g'(x)$ to get:

$$
\int f(u)du = P(u) + C
$$

He explains that if that mechanical process is used in reverse,it becomes the method of integration by substitution and that the reader should realize that we have attached no meanings to the symbols $dx$ and $du$ by themselves.

Later, in section $6.16$ when explaining how to use $\int e^x dx = e^x + C$ more generally, he says that we can replace $x$ with $u$, *which is any function with a continuous derivative*.

I'm looking for help to consolidate the two things:

1. Attaching no meaning to symbol $du$ when introducing integration by substitution.
2. Requiring that $u$ has a continuous derivative in section $6.16$.

Is $u$ always required to have a continuous derivative, or the case in section $6.16$ is a special case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution Theorem 5.4 there addresses the question. The paraphrased theorem is:

If $g$ has a continuous derivative on an open interval $I$ and $f$ is continuous on the domain of $g$, then for each $x$ and $c$ in $I$, we have:

$$
\int_{c}^{x} f[g(t)]g'(t)dt = \int_{g(c)}^{g(x)} f(u) du
$$

Therefore, the quote I gave from section $5.7$ was from a more descriptive part of the section, and the end of that section contains the more formal theorem, which has the requirement on $g$ to have a continuous derivative. As far as I see, the symbol $dg$ still does not need to have meaning on itself.

It seems that the theorem could sometimes hold even if the derivative of $g$ is not continuous, but that's relevant at the moment...